# With JS set color or background color for Disabled button

Tags: javascript, html, css

guys somebody can set color, or background color with js to disabled button?

```js
 const btn = document.getElementById('interval')
 btn.disabled = true;
 btn.style.background_color = 'white';
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="interval">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `btn.style["background-color"]` instead of  `btn.style.background_color`

```js
 const btn = document.getElementById('interval')
 btn.disabled = true;
 btn.style["background-color"] = 'white';
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="interval">Button</button>
```